# I am using typescript and I am getting error TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, typeerror, nats-streaming-server

I am building a microservice app which has a nats streaming setup, but when I create a instance of my listener class I get the error

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
[company]     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/events/listeners/tenant-created-listener.ts:8:44)
[company]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
[company]     at Module._compile (/app/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
[company]     at Module.m._compile (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-9408356301483605.js:69:33)
[company]     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
[company]     at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-9408356301483605.js:114:20)
[company]     at require.extensions.<computed> (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-9408356301483605.js:71:20)
[company]     at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/app/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
[company]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
[company]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
[company] [ERROR] 10:38:48 TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

my files are

- The issue is when I creating this instance
  [image: The issue is when I creating this instance]
- The issue points to here
  [image: The issue points to here]
- This is the listener class which I am extending
  [image: This is the listener class which I am extending]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post pictures of code as it's hard to replicate the issue. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `declare` in typescript, you're telling the compiler to not generate the class.

So at runtime when you extends your abstract class, the parent class `listener` is not defined.

Just remove your declare and you'll be fine:

`abstract class listener<T> { ... }`

Comment: I removed it and converted the Listener class, now there is another error as 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TenantCreated')
[company]     at new TenantCreatedListener (/app/src/events/listeners/tenant-created-listener.ts:22:46)
[company]     at /app/index.ts:39:4
[company]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
[company]     at fulfilled (/app/index.ts:5:58)
[company]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[company] Listening on port 3000!!!!!!!!
inside the tenantCreated class